# Rails Active Admin mismo recurso en distintos namespace, ¡como hacer para no repetir?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo un Modelo `Comercio` y como recurso esta en varios namespace. ¿existe alguna forma de aplicar require, include, load o herencia?. Para no tener todo el archivo repetido donde el único cambio es el namespace.

Comment: No entiendo a que te refieres con hacer require o herencia. ¿quieres heredar desde `Comercio` a otro modelo similar? ¿o distintas definiciones de tu modelo `Comercio` quieres que estén disponibles para todos tus namespaces?. Por favor, edita tu pregunta y agregar el código del que hablas, al menos las partes que son relevantes a tu duda. Saludos

Comment: No lo que quiero es un mismo modelo presentarlo en distintos namespace, sin repetirlo, como son exactamente iguale y solo cambia el namespace, por ahora lo que hago es copiarlo mediante un script echo en ruby.